# Error When Trying To Read Int From Txt File Python

Tags: python, file, valueerror, file-writing, file-read

Im trying to do a highscore system for my python game using a txt file and writing and reading the highscore from/to it.
When i try the code under i get this error message:
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '\x003'

```
highscorefileR = open(r"highscore.txt","r+")

score =  int(score)

highscore = highscorefileR.read(3)

for line in highscore:
 
    for i in line:
     
        # Checking for the digit in
        # the string
        if i.isdigit() == True:
            score = int(score)
            highscore.rstrip("\x003")
            highscore.rstrip("\x00")
            highscore.rstrip(" \t\r\n\0")
            highscore = int(highscore)
            if score >= highscore+1:
                score = str(score)
                score.rstrip(' \t\r\n\0')
                highscorefileW = open(r"highscore.txt","w")
                highscore = score
                highscorefileR.write(score)


print(highscore)
```

Comment: `highscore` is not a list of lines, it's just the first 3 characters of the file. So `for line in highscore:` makes no sense.

Comment: `highscore.rstrip("\x003")` doesn't do anything. The function doesn't modify the string in place (strings are immutable), it returns a new string, so you need to assign the result back to the variable.

Comment: thanks Barmar it helped with the error but now i get this error:ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Comment: You have an empty string in the file.

Comment: How are you writing the score to the file? Why do you need to strip all these characters?

Comment: Does the file contain a single score, or many scores?

Comment: I just have 1 integer in my file

Answer (score 0):

If it's a plain text file, you shouldn't need all that complication. Just:

```
with open(r"highscore.txt","r") as highscorefileR:
    highscore = int(highscorefileR.read())

if score > highscore:
    with open(r"highscore.txt","w") as highscorefileW:
        highscorefileW.write(f'{score}\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

I just Took Highscore = i
instead of all of this:
`highscore.rstrip("\x003") highscore.rstrip("\x00") highscore.rstrip(" \t\r\n\0") highscore = int(highscore)`

Because i looks for the digits in the file

Thanks For all your answers!